# Distribution of Data in HDFS Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I configured 3 datanodes on my Linux machine. In my configuration, I configured the number of replication to be 1.

I am submitting a file to the hdfs, and found that the file has 3 copies on each datanodes (I checked it from the browser)

Isn't right that I should only see the file on 1 datanodes and on 1 replica?

Comment: How did you check it from the browser?

Comment: localhost:50070, there I have 3 datanodes, and found that the file is available in each datanode

Answer (score 1):

Before going into the HDFS the file will be split into blocks and you should see one replica of each block on each datanode. The file as a whole won't be present on any of the datanode.

Please make sure that you have restarted HDFS daemons after changing the replication factor property in the hdfs-site.xml file.

Also It would be good if you can post your HDFS Console Snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that `dfs.replication` is set to `3` instead of 1

Make sure that below parameters are set to 1 in your `hdfs-site.xml`

`dfs.replication` : Default block replication. The actual number of replications can be specified when the file is created. The default is used if replication is not specified in create time

`dfs.namenode.replication.min` : Minimal block replication.

Have a look at [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) for more details.